# Multiline UILabel with right-to-left text and auto adjusted font size

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, right-to-left

Below is the code in Swift I used for a 2 line UILabel with `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth` set to `true`, working properly for left-to-right text. I have used [EasyPeasy](https://github.com/nakiostudio/EasyPeasy) library for setting layout constraints.

```
let contactLabel = UILabel()
contactLabel.text = "Tell us how we can contact you".localized()
contactView.addSubview(contactLabel)
contactLabel.easy.layout([Leading(), Trailing(), Top(20), Height(60)])
contactLabel.numberOfLines = 2
contactLabel.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingHead
contactLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
```

When I changed the language to Arabic, the text will be broken to two lines properly but shown in LTR mode instead of RTL. How should manage a multiline label to show Arabic text?

I also checked this behavior on iOS 11 and it is working, maybe there is a trick to it in iOS 12.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]Don't set a specific height because of that is not expanding to your amount of text.

Steps 1 - Set **top, leading, trailing and height constraint** and change height relation to **Greater Than or Equal to**

Step 2 - `label.numberOfLines = 0`

Step 3 - `label.sizeToFit()`

step 4 - `label.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingTail`

Comment: There is enough space just for two lines, therefore, both `label.numberOfLines = 2` and `label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true` are required so that it would fit on different size of screens

Comment: tried the code with the constraint on height to be less than or equal to maximum height available (`Height(<=70)`) but didn't work

Comment: I upload a image can you please check?

Comment: Sorry for late response, I did understand what you meant without this image too. From your answer, I now know I should change my layout design so that I won't have to set the height constraint. tnx

Answer (score 1):

Although setting the label alignment to "natural" works in most cases, iOS sometimes gets it wrong. If you're out of ideas, you can always set it manually in the code based on the current layout direction of the application.

```
    if UIApplication.shared.userInterfaceLayoutDirection == .leftToRight {
        resultLabel.textAlignment = .left
    } else {
        resultLabel.textAlignment = .right
    }
```